# Best 28 result into the sum

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum

I have the following QUERY and I need only the sum of the best 28 results

```
SELECT id_person, sum(points) 
FROM ranking 
WHERE id_open>=847 and id_club=2 and id_person!='91' 
GROUP BY id_person
ORDER BY sum(points) desc, id_ranking
```

Each player (id_person), in this serie (id_open=847 or more), in this club (id_club=2) can play about 56 games, but only 28 best result counts for ranking, in other words, I'll despise 28 worst results.

** **EDITED QUERY** ** (id_ranking isn't necessary in ORDER BY)

```
SELECT id_person, sum(points) 
FROM ranking 
WHERE id_open>=847 and id_club=2 and id_person!='91' 
GROUP BY id_person
ORDER BY sum(points) desc
```

Comment: What is definition of **best 28 results**?

Comment: i think you need `LIMIT 28` ?

Comment: I need the sum of the 28 best scores of "points" field!

Comment: Provide some sample dataset with expected result set as well and would be better you provide your table definition [*`@sql fiddle`*](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly...

**Your goal:** Display players (i.e. `id_person`) in `DESC` order based on how many `points` that person makes in his/her **best 28** games.

Here is a query that potentially does that:

```
SELECT id_person, sum(points) as s
FROM (
SELECT id_person,
       points,
       @rownum := if(@person = id_person, @rownum + 1, 1) as pointRank,
       @person := id_person as dummy
FROM (SELECT id_person, points
      FROM ranking
      WHERE id_open >= 847 and id_club = 2 and id_person != '91'
      ORDER BY id_person, points DESC
     ) as q1,
     (SELECT @rownum := 0) as r,
     (SELECT @person := '') as s
) as q2
WHERE pointRank <= 28
GROUP BY id_person
ORDER BY s DESC;
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea89c/2)** (*Note: leaves out q1's `WHERE` clause for convenience*)

***Subquery q1 explanation***:

1. Filters out rows based on `id_open`, `id_club`, and `id_person`.
2. Then, orders based on `id_person` (implicitly `ASC`) and `points` (explicitly `DESC`).
3. Finally, selects the `id_person` and `points` fields.

*Note: MySQL Group By's are a little special - aggregates will work, but if selecting non-aggregates, a random row will be selected for the group by, not all rows ([MYSQL-Group-By-returns-only-first-row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10830660/mysql-group-by-returns-only-first-row))*

***Subquery q2 explanation***:

1. Adds in `rownum` and `person` variables to keep track of ranking of game. ([generate-column-containing-record-index-in-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126972/with-mysql-how-can-i-generate-a-column-containing-the-record-index-in-a-table))
2. Needs to use the `(SELECT @rownum := 0) as r` and `(SELECT @person := '') as s` to set the variables. (These variables could be set outside too.)
3. `if(@person := id_person, @rownum + 1, 1)` is necessary to reset the ranking of games per person.

*Note: Important to initialize the `person` variable to an empty string, as opposed to 0. Not too sure why, but if you do not, then it will not reset the `rownum` variable correctly.*

***Overall query explanation***:

1. All row numbers (i.e. `pointRank`) less than or equal to 28 (basically, the 28 best point scores per `id_person`) are kept.
2. After this filtering, each `id_person` will be grouped again.
3. Finally, the top 28 games' `points` will be summed up and labeled as `s`, and these pairs (`id_person`,`s`) will be ordered from highest to lowest.

Here is another StackOverflow question with a good article link inside (highly recommended read): ([limit-within-group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/mysql-using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group))

**Note: I cannot guarantee this will work though, since I do not know what your table looks like. That information would help.**

Comment: Use LIMIT in this query will limit my result in 28 rows ... when I really need that SUM only add 28 best scores!

Comment: Do you only want the sum back?

Comment: Each player (id_person), in this serie (id_open=847 or more), in this club (id_club=2) can play about 56 games, but only 28 best result counts for ranking, in other words, I'll despise 28 worst results.

Comment: So are you saying for a given player (i.e. `id_person`), you want to show that person's 28 best games (out of the 56 they played)? And you rank the games based on the number of points the person made in that game? How does `id_ranking` factor in?

Comment: That's it! Rank a player for the sum of points from best 28 games ... Any idea?! 
About id_ranking in ORDER BY ... I think that's not necessary! I'll edit!

Comment: this query with variables works great, but I have 276 players in this circuit and I need show everyone, but only the best 28 result from each one! The query show me only 28 players ... when I really need all players with the best 28 games points added.

Comment: I do not see anything in my query that limits it to 28 players. Look at the modified one. Also, refer to the SQL Fiddle created.

Comment: So you want to see each of the 28 games per player, not just the sum of those games? It would help if you were more clear with your question.

Comment: Sorry, query works great ... but sums return just a last record, not all 28 best points added!

Comment: Hmmm, have you checked out the SQL Fiddle? Based on those results, it adds up all of the top best points. Can you modify the SQL Fiddle and post a link to it better emulating your work environment?

Comment: Man, works like a heaven!
I don't know how to thank, but, if I can do anything ... dont hesitate!

Comment: So the above query works for you? Because if so, then what you could do is accept it as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Any time. Thanks for being responsive in the comments!